# Vim: What is difference between motion mark shotcut `. and `"?

Tags: vim

While reading vim info motion marker says:

```
|`quote|   `"           go to the position when last editing this file
|`.|       `.           go to the position of the last change in this file
```

Above two shortcuts seem to be same. I tried both on a new file. first is taking me to the start of file(incorrect, unexpected behaviour), while later is working correctly as written. What is difference between two shortcuts?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have misread / miscopied the information. Let's revisit the `:help` topics:

> ```
> '"  `"            To the cursor position when last exiting the current
>                   buffer.  Defaults to the first character of the first
>                   line.
> ```

This is about **exiting** (or leaving) the buffer. The second sentence also explains the behavior on a new file.

> ```
> '.  `.            To the position where the last change was made.
> ```

Only this mark is about **modifications**. Also handy: `gi`, which jumps to the last insert position and goes to insert mode.

Answer (score 1):

'" -> goes to the line you edited last
'. -> hilights the curly braces { } in which your last edit took place.